# Authentication error building a job with a patch file

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, patch

I am trying to build  a jenkins job using the library [python-jenkins](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Now this works fine if I try it with a normal data file using the command:

```
j.build_job('test', {'param1' : filepath})
```

Here `j` is the Jenkins instance I use for my server and `filepath` is the path of the file which is to be passed as the parameter. This works fine. But when I try this for a patch file to be passed as a parameter, it shows the following error message.

> `JenkinsException: Error in request. Possibly authentication failed [500]: Server Error`

I have installed the Patch parameter plugin in Jenkins and the job is already configured to take a patch file as a parameter just like it was configured for a normal file. Then why does this error message appear? Please help.